# Can I change aperture with a Nikon TC-200 2x teleconverter?

Tags: nikon, teleconverter

I'm using a 2X teleconverter with a Nikon 35mm 1.8 AF lens on my D7100. It looks like I can't change the aperture with any of the camera's dials. Am I missing something?

The converter is a Nikon TC-200 (non AF).....with further inspection, I can see there's no way the camera can connect with the lens so perhaps that's the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The Nikon TC-200 was designed for older lens ~1977 (AI I believe). Back then lens were manually focused and aperture controls are on the lens. That TC is meant for lens shorter than 200mm which the 35mm is but it's a modern G lens that lacks aperture control.

There are many AF lens, pre G, that offer an aperture control but yours is not one of them. More importantly most modern Teleconverters are meant for longer lens that don't have a rear element close to the sensor, 100mm or longer. Your best bet is to buy a longer lens if you want a longer reach rather than use a TC that has other consequences like IQ and light loss.

Answer (score 0):

If your teleconverter has no conection pins, and your lens is electronic you can not.

If your lens is manual yes you can.

There is a small lever in the back of your lens. If it is really necesary you could smoothly stuck a firm pice of cardboard on it, so the aperture is closed all the way. You will see darker in live view and on the visor, but you can expose that way in manual mode. Keep in mind that autofocus feature will suffer from this hack, as the sensor for it will also get less light.

Use a material that does not leave particles, and that can be removed gently.

Comment: Many Pre-G lens offer some form of electronic control/AF that do have aperture control. One example is my Nikon 300/4 AF lens.